# some error in redirecting from all old domain url to new domain url

Tags: .htaccess, url, dns, redirect

When redirecting to old website url page to new website url, it result like this:
www.newdomain.comabout.html/

But I want like this:
www.newdomain.com/about.htm

My old website url is like this:
www.olddomain.com/about.html
www.olddomain.com/contact.html
www.olddomain.com/location.html

And my new website url is like this:
www.newdomain.com/about.htm
www.newdomain.com/contact.htm
www.newdomain.com/location.htm

You can notice, I have changed file extension from html to htm in new domain.

**I tried this in editing old domain .htaccess file:**
Redirect 301 /about.html http://www.newdomain.com/about.htm

And also tried this (inserted in old domain url):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.newdomain.com/about.htm">
```

Both not works. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code in your `.htaccess` file of olddomain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\.htm)l$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```